# How to write an array of numbers through file descriptors

Tags: c

Hi i want to write numbers from 0 to 255 to fd, can someone pls correct the errors in the below file? Thanks in advance

Code: Actually need to increse / decrese the brightness of an led connected to a particular port. so i need to write these numbers to the specified file called brightness.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(void)
{
    int fd, t;
    char buf[300];
    char z;
while(1)
{
   fd = open("/sys/class/leds/pwmD0/brightness", O_WRONLY);
   if (fd < 0)
    {
        abort();
    }
for(t=0;t<10000000;t++);      //random sw delay
for(z=0;z<255;z++)
{
write(fd, "%s", strlen(z));
printf("Received: %s\n",buf[z]);
}
for(t=0;t<10000000;t++);
for(z=255;z>0;z--)
{
write(fd, "%s", strlen(z));
printf("Received: %s\n",buf[z]);
}
close(fd);
}
}
```

Comment: Please format your code so it is better readable (proper indenting of every block).

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  Please re-compile with all warnings enabled, fix the warnings (not hide them) the re-post the code with, using consistent indentation.  suggest 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before each closing brace '}'  a blank line between code blocks would also greatly assist in making the code easily readable by us humans

Comment: suggest using 'exit(-1)' rather than 'abort()'

Comment: there are two valid ways to write the main function declaration (and one other acceptable way)  void main( void ) is not one of them.  suggest: 'int main ( void )'    and naturally, need to add a 'return(0)' at the end of the main function.

Comment: the '#include <stdint.h:' and '#include <fcntl.h>' header file contents are not used, so to help keep you code simple, they should not be included

Comment: the contents of buf[] are initially garbage and are never updated, so the calls to printf()  may send control characters to the terminal, resulting in unwanted terminal characteristics changes.   Suggest removing all references to buf[], or at least initialization to some printable string that is (at least)256 bytes long.

Comment: regarding the purpose of the function: the question did not mention the hardware platform.  However, there are hints that the file being written to is actually a PWM peripheral.  If so, such peripherals usually require some amount of setup, like the total pulse time and type of pulse and max voltage. and certain other configuration details.  the posted code does not seem to be handling any of those details and if the device is a PWM, then writes to it should be no oftener than the overall pulse width time.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
write(fd, "%s", strlen(z));
```

makes no sense, the `write()` function is not `printf()`. Read more documentation.

You need something like:

```
char buf[32];

const size_t len = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d\n", z);
write(fd, buf, len);
```